# OpenGL ES function

Tags: opengl-es

may I ask whether the OpenGL ES got set function and get function?? This is because I know that Java got this function when we set the value , we manage to retrieve and change it. However, I want to set the rotation, scale and other value of my 3D object in OpenGL ES and able to retrieve it. This means that after the user click the 3D object, he /she able to set the value of rotation and get the output of my 3D object..So, how to do it? Any guideline to do this? I want the user can set the value in the interface and manage to see the output on the screen. Thanks.:D

Answer (score 0):

You're after higher-level [scenegraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph#Scene_graphs_in_games_and_3D_applications)-type functionality.

Comment: thanks so much..I already refer what u have given. Actually, I already import my 3d object from maya to the OpenGL ES. Thus, I really do not know how to make a function so that user can freely set the rotation point, scale the object.any guideline? :D